# Beating Buzz Aldrin's Space Program Manager in the decade

Tags: buzz-aldrins-space-program-manager

What is a good strategy to beat Buzz Aldrin's Space Program Manager to get astronauts to the moon and back before 69? Even with great reliability my rockets and capsules fail sometimes and throw me back a year or more.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want a strategy guide? I can give you that!

Comment: I was more looking for some reason why my rockets keep exploding rather than a complete guide.

Comment: Ok, il help you fix your question to revolve around that.